# Create gallery with images in Excel

Tags: vb.net, excel, gallery, ribbon

I am trying to make smth like this:
[image]

For now I use the `imageMso` attribute just for testing purposes. Even though, nothing really happens.

That's the XML for the gallery:

```
    <customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabAddIns" label="Gallery">
        <group id="grpGallery" label="Example Gallery">
          <gallery id="galleryID" label="My Gallery" columns="3" rows="2" size="large"
                   itemHeight="100" itemWidth="100"
                   getItemID="CallbackGetItemID"
                   getItemCount="CallbackGetItemsCount"
                   getItemImage="CallbackGetItemImage"
                   getItemScreentip="CallbackGetItemScreentip"
                   getItemSupertip="CallbackGetItemSupertip">
            <item id="galImg1" imageMso="PictureBrightnessGallery"/>
            <item id="galImg2" imageMso="ZoomPrintPreviewExcel"/>
          </gallery>

....
```

And the VB code to it:

```
    Public idCounter As Integer

    Public Sub New()
        idCounter = 0
    End Sub

    Public Function GetCustomUI(ByVal ribbonID As String) As String Implements Office.IRibbonExtensibility.GetCustomUI
        Return GetResourceText("GalleryTest.Gallery.xml")
    End Function

#Region "Ribbon Callbacks"
    Public Sub Ribbon_Load(ByVal ribbonUI As Office.IRibbonUI)
        Me.galleryRibbon = ribbonUI
    End Sub

    Public Sub CallbackGetItemID(control As Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonControl, _
                                 index As Integer, ByRef itemID As Integer)
        itemID = idCounter
        idCounter += 1
    End Sub

    Public Sub CallbackGetItemsCount(control As Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonControl, _
                                        ByRef count As Integer)
        count = 6
    End Sub

    Public Sub CallbackGetItemScreentip(control As Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonControl, _
                                        Index As Integer, ByRef screentip As String)
        screentip = "Screentip"
    End Sub

    Public Sub CallbackGetItemSupertip(control As Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonControl, _
                                       Index As Integer, ByRef supertip As String)
        'TO DO'
    End Sub
```

As you see, it's nothing fancy. I am just getting into the vb.net + excel world. What happens is that I get the "My Gallery" button for the dropdown, in the excel tab, but it is empty. No elements. Not even the dummy items.

Any suggestions?

P.S. I followed [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548011(v=office.12).aspx#acc2007_expertaccessprogramming_Images)

Answer (score 0):

Try to return actual values in the callbacks. For example, I see non-existing IDs in the callback.

There is no need to add the **CallbackGetItemsCount** callback for the gallery control if you specified items explicitly.

You can read more about the Ribbon UI in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: What do you mean by actual values and non-existing IDs? I increment the ID and return it for each element.

Comment: Is there such items with IDs specified in the callback?